# Sending emails using outlook with Python - Overcoming Azure Information Protection Classifications

Tags: python, azure, email, outlook, azure-information-protection

I am using win32com to create emails, but with Azure Information Protection now enabled how do I select the classification from within python.

I have 2 solutions so far: turn off AIP or manually select the classification, is there any way to automate it from the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,any updates ? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are running the python script to create emails on the azure web app. As I know , azure web app runs in a sandbox. I searched the `General Sandbox Restrictions` from this [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#access-to-out-of-process-com-servers) and found the restrictions of COM servers as below:

> Windows Servers have a bunch of COM servers configured and available
>   for consumption by default; however the sandbox prevents access to all
>   out-of-proc COM servers. For example, a sandboxed application cannot
>   call into WMI, or into MSIServer.

So, in fact, we could use [Azure SendGrid Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) to post emails instead of `win32corn`.

This is [Azure SendGrid Python SDK](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/python.html) and [Azure SendGrid pricing rules](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/).

Hope it helps you.