# Azure information protection in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-information-protection

I am using win32com to create emails, but with Azure Information Protection now enabled how do I select the classification from within python.

I have 2 solutions so far: turn off AIP or manually select the classification, is there any way to automate it from the script?

Comment: Have you checked the answer provided to a similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559604/10805761 ?